# How to convert the following date format into required format

Tags: java, datetime

I am receiving date in the following format from a third party data provider

**Friday Oct 30**

Is it possible to convert this above into the following format

**30-Oct-2015**

(All dates belongs to 2015 )

Comment: Come on, google for "how to parse a date in Java" and read one of the hundreds of results you'll get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are shure that the format looks like that you could do something like:

```
    String origin = "Friday Oct 30";

    String[] split = origin.split(" ");

    String newString = split[2] + "-" + split[1] + "-2015";
    //System.out.println(newString);
```

Comment: We can use the SimpleDateFormat or DateFormat classes to format the date instead of split the string.

Comment: @Thanigaiarasu Shure, but why use a complex class if the use case is that easy?

Comment: In case the format changes or service send the date in differnent format. we should make the change in client as well. Java has util classes for the dates (Not a Complex class), make use of it. This split will create 3 String objects in the String pool.